# flex-wrap not working in Safari and float left isn't an option

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a setup where I am trying to have a div centered in the screen, yet the images within the div flex-wrap based on the parent divs width.

This works in all browsers except Safari.
float: left; won't work due to the centering issue.
I have a fiddle with the scene broken down...

http://jsfiddle.net/6f59t7qh/2/

```
<div class="gallery">
    <div class="galleryBlock">
        <div class="galleryTile">
            <img src="http://hdcomputerwallpaper.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/Puppy-images.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="galleryTile">
            <img src="http://hdcomputerwallpaper.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/Puppy-images.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="galleryTile">
            <img src="http://hdcomputerwallpaper.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/Puppy-images.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="galleryTile">
            <img src="http://hdcomputerwallpaper.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/Puppy-images.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="galleryTile">
            <img src="http://hdcomputerwallpaper.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/Puppy-images.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="galleryTile">
            <img src="http://hdcomputerwallpaper.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/Puppy-images.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="galleryTile">
            <img src="http://hdcomputerwallpaper.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/Puppy-images.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.gallery {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: green;
}

.galleryBlock {
    width: 585px;
    display: -webkit-inline-flex;
    display: -ms-inline-flexbox;
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap; /* flex-wrap not working in Safari*/
    background-color: red;
}
.galleryTile {
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
    width: 190px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
}
```

any thoughts would be great!
Thanks.

Comment: Safari 6.1 and up [requires the `-webkit-` prefix](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox): `-webkit-flex-wrap`. Previous versions (6 and below) do not support the current specification.

Comment: Tried that but didn't work.. bummer... I must be missing something else.

Answer (score 0):

Check this:
[center a block and set its children flex](http://jsfiddle.net/1g69zd0y/)

1.You should always set the size of your image in px of percentage. if it's flexible

```
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
```

so the image could change with its parent's size.

2.just use these two can set a block horizontal center. text-align is not appropriate in this situation.

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

3.set .galleryBlock

```
display: -webkit-flex; /* Safari */
display: flex;
```

and set .galleryTile

```
-webkit-flex: 1;  /* Safari 6.1+ */
-ms-flex: 1;  /* IE 10 */    
flex: 1;
```

Here's [flex tutorial in W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.asp)

Comment: Hi ronan,
1. yes, i am handling the image differently, this is just a test there, the shape of the box and layout is whats important here.
2. yes, that is a better way to handle centering, unfortunately the margin left/right wasn't working in all browsers with this scenario so I left it thinking it wouldn't matter, probably does.. good point!
3. unfortunately the fiddle you have wasn't maintaining the spirit of the layout.

I have updated the fiddle with some of the thoughts so far

http://jsfiddle.net/6f59t7qh/5/
    flex-wrap: -webkit-wrap;

Comment: @JWoodright  Updated: http://jsfiddle.net/1g69zd0y/3/  .  Try drag you browser width to make it narrow and you'll see the effect. Do you need this effect?

Comment: yes it does, but you are using float:left and not the flex-wrap anymore.  Works just fine and I am going back to that.. I was just trying to find a similar solution using a new method.  Thanks for helping pull me out of that spiral.. :-)